# What is the purpose of Vsense terminal in some amplifiers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-amplifier

I am playing with old power op amps like Sanyo LA6510 : https://www.alldatasheet.fr/datasheet-pdf/pdf/40213/SANYO/LA6510.html

I would like to know the purpose of Vsense terminal ?

Additionaly I don't understand how to wire it. According the spec in Pinout, pin 1 is Vsense1, pin 2 is Out1.
But in Application notes, it's the opposite !

And there are no values advices for resistor.
For example I would like to use it as a simple factor 1 time not inverting amplifier.
I tried with 1k resistors wired as in application note but the output seem to oscillate with high frequency (1MHz) noise of several volts.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a better data sheet](https://pl-1.org/getproductfile.axd?id=1252&filename=LA6510.pdf) for the LA6510 power op-amp and, it shows how Vsense should be used: -

[image]

Basically Vsense is a pin that can be used to sense the voltage developed across RSC. In other words, it's an output current limit protection facility.

> *I tried with 1k resistors wired as in application note but the output
> seem to oscillate with high frequency (1MHz) noise of several volts.*

The value of the resistor will be in the ohms range and not the kohm range: -

[image]

The data sheet I have linked gives values for components.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of detective work...

[image]

Pin 2 is output, pin 1 is vsense.

There is Rsc between them, so between the output (pin 2) and the load.

There is a line in the table "Limiting current" Isc=0.35A for Rsc=2.2 ohms.

I believe this is a current limiter / short circuit protection. Rsc is the current sense resistor, the chip measures voltage between Out and Vsense, and a circuit inside the chip does something when current gets over the limit.